# Localize sticker pack images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, localization, xcode8

I want to add **sticker pack** to my existing app.

Is it possible to localize images in this pack?

I saw there are two buttons in the attributes inspector panel : "Export Localizations" and "Import localization"

Maybe they are used to it ?